# SQL Count function query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having a little trouble trying with the count function in SQL.

What I am attempting is to count the amount of people with a certain name

For example:

```
Name | Number
==============
Ivan | 9      
Brody| 8
Ray  | 7
```

And where there are the same instance sort alphabetically.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `COUNT()` which is an `AGGREGATE FUNCTION` it needs to have `GROUP BY` Clause. Try this,

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(name)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC
```

or you can just add `ALIAS` on it

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(name) totalCount
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
```

Comment: Thats perfect except I need it to be sorted by the largest number of names first :)

Comment: @user1650499 do you mean `name` that has many count? if so, change it to `ORDER BY COUNT(NAME) DESC`

Comment: @user1650499 you can also add alias on it, see the updated answer above :)

Comment: @user1650499 don't forget to accept answers if it really helped you a lot :)

Comment: +1 for adding `s` to the end of `need` ... and also being correct :)